# C++ join function that works on strings and chars

Tags: c++

I've written a join() function that works on iterators, with this signature:

```
template <typename Iter>
string join(Iter begin, Iter end, string sep = ", ");
```

I'd like to work for both iterators to strings and iterators to chars. But it uses `string::append(*iter)`, which doesn't work for chars. How can I specialize it?

Edit: Here is my implementation. It works great for collections of strings, but not collections of chars.

```
template <typename Iter>
string join(Iter begin, Iter end, string sep = ", ") {
    string result;
    for (Iter i = begin; i != end; ++i) {
        if (result.size() > 0) {
            result.append(sep);
        }
        result.append(*i); // <-- fails if called with a collection of chars
    }
    return result;
}
```

@HolyBlackCat's suggestion of += makes it work!

Comment: `+=` perhaps? Show the function body.

Comment: Why are you passing iterators instead of passing the string and deriving the iterators from there? You could also use std::transform, or simply append a new string, which can take a char as a constructor parameter

Answer (score 1):

As @HolyBlackCat mentioned, you should be able to use [the `+=` operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%2B%3D) here. In general you could create concepts though to create overloads for the relevant functionality:

```
template<class Iterator>
concept StringIterator = requires(Iterator i)
{
    { *i } -> std::convertible_to<std::string const&>;
};

template<class Iterator>
concept CharIterator = requires(Iterator i)
{
    { *i } -> std::convertible_to<char>;
};

template<StringIterator Iter>
void Append(std::string& target, Iter pos)
{
    target.append(*pos);
}

template<CharIterator Iter>
void Append(std::string& target, Iter pos)
{
    target.push_back(*pos);
}

template<class Iter>
std::string join(Iter begin, Iter end, std::string const& sep = ", ")
{
    std::string result;
    if (begin != end)
    {
        Append(result, begin);
        
        for (++begin; begin != end; ++begin)
        {
            result += sep;
            Append(result, begin);
        }
    }
    return result;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<std::string> strings{ "foo", "bar", "baz"};
    std::string s = "Hello World";
    std::cout << join(strings.begin(), strings.end()) << '\n';
    std::cout << join(s.begin(), s.end()) << '\n';
}
```